# Unable to update a component after a download

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton` that downloads a file:

```html
<p:commandButton
    value="download"
    ajax="false"
    action="#{myBean.download()}"
>
</p:commandButton>
```

At the end of `myBean.download()`, I added

```java
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":myComponentId");
```

Unluckily, despite `myBean` changes (I see it using the debugger), the component does not update. I used `:myComponentId` in the `update` of many "normal" `p:commandButton`s without problem.

What's the issue? I'm using Mojarra 2.1.7 and Primefaces 3.4.1 and I can't update the software :)

Comment: @JasperdeVries But I added the update in the action, not in the `p:commandButton`

Comment: @JasperdeVries and there's not a workaround? Must I redirect the entire page?